# (in parent os.close(w) OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor) why am i getting this error while i try pipe between parent and child process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, fork, ipc

import os
from multiprocessing import Pipe
import sys
import time

```
def child(w):

    msg = ("Spam").encode()
    os.write(w, msg)
```

```
def parent():

    r, w = os.pipe()
    Pn = os.fork()
    while True:
        # -------------------------------------------------------------------

        if Pn < 0:
            print("error occured")
        if Pn == 0:

            os.close(r)
            child(w)

            

        else:

            os.close(w)
            pipein = os.fdopen(r)

            line = pipein.readline()
            print("Parent %d got [%s] at %s" %
                  (os.getpid(),  line,  time.time()))
parent()
```

I think there is a problem since I used os.close(r) but I don't understand how and why.